# Macbook pro 13 2017 model. screen is very delicate. are screeen replacements reliable?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, screen, repair

so i closed my space grey 2017 macbook pro 13" ( i opted for the model without the touch bar) after a lecture and was going to put it in my backpack , but when i closed it, the edge of my zip up hoodie got caught in the macbook (picture the macbook eating my hoodie zipper). It was a very short part of the hoodie just above my abdomen that got caught so i simply pulled it out and closed the macbook all the way.

while at the library, i notice a scratch on the screen next to where the facetime camera is; it looked like a stray mark you make with a pen on a paper about 1.5cm long, of course i said WTF?! howTF!?

i immediately realized one of the teeth from the zipper must have scratched when i pulled the hoodie.
I have a macbook pro 17" that i let my sister have because it was getting too bulky to lug around campus and that thing was as sturdy as a rock, this happened to me with my 17" and it never scratched, I must have dropped that thing at least 5 times from high up on shelves (granted it fell on the carpet everytime, but even so any plastic dell or HP would have gone to shit).

I digress, does anyone have an idea what a new glass screen would cost? and if it would be worth it?

i know iphone screen replacements are for the most part shotty, but macbooks arent touchscreen so i suppose they would be easier to maintainn and would last longer.

I have seen another on this forum who closed the same model space grey macbook with the plug from his ipod earphones caught and it literally punched a hole in the lower part of his screen; i would not replace it unless I literally could not see the letters on the screen, but does anyone know if OWC or any other company besides apple can repair this screen? at leas the glass part of the screen, not the LCD???

**NOTE: If you own this computer or similar model be very careful when closing the screeeen!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!**

Comment: Right now, they only source for 3rd party screens will be Apple; basically, your model is too new.  Unfortunately, Apple now permanently adheres the glass to the LCD so replacing the glass is no longer an option.  Based on previous replacements I've had to do for clients, you could estimate between $500 and $750 for the replacement including labor.  You may want to invest in a [screen protector](http://amzn.to/2Gg02OE) for the future; it's cheap insurance.

Comment: I am afraid that a screen protector would be too thick to completely close the screen all the way, I bought a cloth keyboard cover to protect the screen after noticing faint imprints of the keyboard on the screen, probably caused by the friction of the keys rubbing against the screen while carrying it in my backpack (the imprints rubbed off), but the screen wouldn't close all the way and I'm afraid the cover's too thick that it might cause the screen to shatter if the MacBook Pro was pressed all the way closed while in my backpack. do you know of any effective protectors that are paper thin?